# WPF download a file and save it in the same time

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I download a file with this method:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadProgressChanged);
webClient.DownloadDataCompleted += new DownloadDataCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadDataCompleted);
webClient.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri(this.Url));
```

And this is how i save it to the disk:

```
void client_DownloadDataCompleted(object sender, DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.Result != null)
            {
                string VideoFile = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\Playtube\\VideoCache\\" + this.id + ".wmv";
                File.WriteAllBytes(VideoFile, e.Result);

                isDownloading = false;
                callbackFinish();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

And i want to know if it possible to download a file and in the same time save it to disk, and not wait until the file finish download to save it.

Comment: There is a method called `WebClient.DownloadFileAsync` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms144196(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [DownloadFileAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144196.aspx) to download it directly to a file.